# ASP.Net MVC, strongly typed view with DateTime not accepted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, strongly-typed-view

I wish to create a view like

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
```

but I get an error saying that DateTime must be a reference type in order to use for parameter TModel.

Fair enough, but I google plenty of examples that implement just what I try to achieve.

Any clues as to what I need to change/install/update?

Any comments welcome,

Anders, Denmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.NET 4 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505144.aspx) doesn't show a constraint on `TModel`, but the [.NET 3.5 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505144(VS.90).aspx) do. I don't know the details of MVC versioning, but my guess is you need to upgrade to version 2 of MVC.

Comment: Ah, but of course! I'm nostalgically hanging on to good ol' 3.5 - guess it's time to upgrade, then (but I am using MVC 2).
Thanks!

Comment: @Anders: Are you using the final release of ASP.NET MVC 2, or a beta?

Comment: I was using a beta (as it turned out!) - I got upgraded to to MVC 2 while I was at it...